# Xubuntu lock screen showing up too late after closed lid

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen

I'm on Xubuntu 20.04.1 on a MacBookAir6,2 running kernel 5.4.0-52-generic. When I close my laptop's lid my screen is supposed to lock. But when I open my lid, the screen turns on and shows the actual content for about 1~2 seconds before turning into the look screen.

This kind of defeats the purpose of the lock screen as you can see the content without unlocking. I am aware that closing and reopening the lid to have a 1~2 second glance at the actual content is tedious, but you shouldn't be able to see the screen even for a millisecond, when it's supposed to be locked.

I can easily reproduce the issue everytime I close my laptop's lid and reopen it. So far I haven't found any similiar issue or possible fix.

Regards
Diadochokinetic

Comment: Somehow a part of my post is missing. I started the post with "Hello,". That part has been cut and even when I edit the post, it gets cut again. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, the problem is `xfce4-screensaver`

I discovered that `Xubuntu 18.04` was working properly, and i saw that uses `light-lock` instead of `xfce4-screensaver`

So first remove it

```
sudo apt remove --purge xfce4-screensaver -y
```

Then install another locker

```
sudo apt install light-locker light-locker-settings -y
```

But I had a lot of problems with it (can't unlock, crash) At first glance, it should have worked, I don't understand.
So I copy pasted `/usr/bin/xflock4` file from `Xubuntu 18.04`

Replace the content in `/usr/bin/xflock4` to this:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

for lock_cmd in \
    "xscreensaver-command -lock" \
    "light-locker-command --lock" \
    "gnome-screensaver-command --lock"
do
    $lock_cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit
done

for lock_cmd in \
    "xlock -mode blank" ~
    "slock"
    do
        set -- $lock_cmd
        if command -v --$1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            $lock_cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 &
            xset dpms force off
            exit
        fi
done

exit 1
```

Optional: Now when you close lid the system hibernate yourself I don't want it so I add `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` If you okay with this you can skip this part.

```
sudo echo "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Or if you need to lock the sessions when you close lid, use `lock` value

```
sudo echo "HandleLidSwitch=lock" >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

And finally reboot the machine.